# How do you filter and display data using a tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift and coding and can't seem to make a filter bar work. I want to display different sets of data depending on what tab is selected. I am getting my data from firebase. I have two sets of data (animals & plants). At the moment they both appear at once. I need the animals array to appear when "animals" is selected on the filter bar and then plants to appear when "plants" is selected on the filter bar.

The code for this project is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FloraFaunaPage: View {
    
    @StateObject var FloraFaunaPageModel = FloraFaunaPageViewModel()
        
    @State private var selectedFloraFaunaFilter: FloraFaunaFilterViewModel = .animals
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
        
        ZStack{
            
            VStack(spacing: 10){
                // MARK: This Is The View For The Filter Bar
                floraFaunaFilterBar
                
                // MARK: This Is The View For The Animals - Fetching From Firebase
                animalCollection
                
                // MARK: This Is The View For The Plants - Fetching From Firebase
                plantCollection
            }
            
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
            self.FloraFaunaPageModel.fetchAnimalData()
            self.FloraFaunaPageModel.fetchPlantData()
            })
        }
    }
```

Part of the view model for the project is:

```
class AchievementPageViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var filteredAnimalPhotos: [AnimalPhoto] = []
    @Published var filteredPlantPhotos: [PlantPhoto] = []
}
```

The view model for my filter bar is this:

```
import Foundation

enum FloraFaunaFilterViewModel: Int, CaseIterable {
    
    case animals
    case plants
    
    var title: String {
        
        switch self {
            
        case .animals: return "Animals"
        case .plants: return "Plants"
        }
    }
}
```

The code for my filter bar view is this:

```
    var floraFaunaFilterBar: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(FloraFaunaFilterViewModel.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.title)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(selectedFloraFaunaFilter == item ? .semibold: .regular)
                        .foregroundColor(selectedFloraFaunaFilter == item ? .black: .gray)
                    
                    if selectedFloraFaunaFilter == item {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color("Blue"))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "filter", in: animation)
                        
                    } else {
                        Capsule()
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.clear))
                            .frame(height: 3)
                        
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        self.selectedFloraFaunaFilter  = item
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .overlay(Divider().offset(x: 0, y: 16))
    }
```

This is the code for my animals array (should appear when "animals" is selected on filter bar):

```
     var animalCollection: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Animals")
            }
            
            HStack {
                if FloraFaunaPageModel.animalPhoto.isEmpty {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    ProgressView()
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                else {
                    ScrollView {
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            HStack{
                                
                                ForEach(FloraFaunaPageModel.filteredAnimalPhotos) {animalPhoto in
                                    
                                    ZStack {
                                        AnimalPhotoView(animalPhoto: animalPhoto)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The code for my plant collection is the same as the animal collection (just with different data)

The issue is I am loading both collections of data when the view appears. Im unsure how to make sure only the animal collection loads on appear and then only the plant collection when "plants" is selected in the filter bar.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use picker view for segmented selection and show list based on that selection.

See the example and let me know if anything goes wrong.

Use a state variable for current selection

```
enum ListType: String {
   case .Animal = "Animal"
   case .Plant = "Plant"
} 
var listOptions = [.Animal, .Plant]
@State private var currentSelection = .Animal
```

Use a segmented style picker to let user select between lists

```
Picker("", selection: $currentSelection) {
         ForEach(listOptions, id: \.self) {
             Text($0.rawValue)
         }
     }
     .pickerStyle(.segmented)
```

And by using a switch control, pick the list you want to display

```
switch currentSelection {
  case .Animal:
    ScrollView {
      LazyVStack() {
        ForEach(YourViewModel.AnimalList, id: \.self) { item in
          YourAnimalRow()
        }
      }
    }
    
  case .Plant:
    ScrollView {
      LazyVStack() {
        ForEach(YourViewModel.PlantList, id: \.self) { item in
           YourPlantRow()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Can not compile for now but hopefully you'll get the idea

Comment: thank you for the response, I'll give this a try later. Just one quick question, would the picker replace the filter tab bar? I ask this because I want both "plants" and "animals to be displayed when the screen is loaded. That's what it currently is like and when "plants" is tapped, I have a bar that goes underneath the word "Plants" to show that's what has been selected. Thanks

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your requirements. Picker wouldn't work in this case.